# Need help Calling methods from another classs

Tags: java, class, methods

I am still new to java, I am struggling to make this program work for my assignment.

Here is the question:

Jeff runs a local retail store in your neighborhood. He has contracted you to create an interactive
application that will assist him in increasing staff salaries. Create a class named Details that will
contain get and set methods for an employee ID number, first name, surname, and salary. Include
a method called getUpdatedSalary() that will increase the staff member's salary by 10%. In your
main class include a static method named `printDetails()` that will produce an employee details
report, also include a static method named `salaryDeductions()` that will display the employee
deductions report if required.

(I know I haven't done the `salaryDeductions` method)

It's outputting everything correctly up until `incAmt` and `newSAl`, these two it just says 0,

I have two classes, StaffSalaries, and Details.
Here is my code:

StaffSalaries.java

```
package staffsalaries;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class StaffSalaries {

    public static void printDetails(Details e ){

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employee ID Number: " + e.getIdNum()
     + "\nEmployee First Name: " + e.getName()
     + "\nEmployee Surname: " + e.getSurname()
     + "\nOrigonal Salary: R" + e.getSalary()
     + "\nIncreass on Salary: R" + e.getincAmt()
     + "\nTotal Salary: R" + e.getnewSal());



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Variables
        String name, surname;
        int idNum;
        double salary, incAmt = 0, newSal = 0;

        //Input
        idNum = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter employee ID number."));
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your first name.");
        surname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your surname");
        salary = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Pleasse enter the salary to be increased."));

        Details e =new Details (idNum, name, surname, salary, incAmt, newSal);
        e.getUpdatedSalary();
        printDetails();

    }

}
```

Details.java

```
package staffsalaries;
public class Details {

    public void getUpdatedSalary () {

        incAmt = salary * 0.1;
        newSal = incAmt + salary;

    }

    //Attributes
    private String name, surname;
    private int idNum;
    private double salary, incAmt, newSal;

    //Constructor
    public Details (int idNum, String name, String surname, double salary, double incAmt, double newSal) {
       this.idNum = idNum;
       this.name = name;
       this.surname = surname;
       this.salary = salary;
       this.incAmt = incAmt;
       this.newSal = newSal;
    }

    //Gettrs
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public int getIdNum() {
        return idNum;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public double getincAmt() {
        return incAmt;
    }

    public Double getnewSal() {
        return newSal;
    }

    //Setters
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public void setIdNum(int idNum) {
        this.idNum = idNum;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public void setincAmt(double incAmt) {
        this.incAmt = incAmt;
    }

    public void setnewSal(double newSal) {
        this.newSal = newSal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep these things in mind. A method is only executed when it is called. You haven't called the method getUpdatedSalary(). Try to figure out where you will call it.

Also the code will word with the way you have defined your current method but take a look at the return type do you really need to return that value?

```
public static void printDetails(Details e ){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employee ID Number: " + e.getIdNum()
     + "\nEmployee First Name: " + e.getName()
     + "\nEmployee Surname: " + e.getSurname()
     + "\nOrigonal Salary: R" + e.getSalary()
     + "\nIncreass on Salary: R" + e.getincAmt()
     + "\nTotal Salary: R" + e.getnewSal());
}
```

Also

```
     salary = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Pleasse enter the saalary to be increased."));
Details e =new Details (idNum, name, surname, salary, incAmt, newSal);
e.getUpdatedSalary();
```

This would've been hard to explain but you should figure out why you needed to do this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214135/discussion-on-answer-by-aditya-kurkure-need-help-calling-methods-from-another-cl).

Answer (score 0):

Change your getUpdatedSalary method to this

```
public void getUpdatedSalary(double salary, double incAmt, double newSal) {
  incAmt = salary * 0.1;
  newSal = incAmt + salary; 
}
```

And call this method `getUpdatedSalary(salary, incAmt, newSal);`
before

```
printDetails(idNum, name, surname, salary, incAmt, newSal)
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions give this a read

Comment: I did that, but it gives me an error saying "Invalid method declaration: return type required. Just to be clear i need to call getUpdatedSalary before printDetails and after public class? @Ashiq K

Comment: @AdityaKurkure I skimmed over it, I'm not asking anyone to do this for me I'm genuinely stuck, I have been for the past 7 hours, I have asked my lecturers but they have not gotten back to me yet, my varsity does allow me to use outside help, they actually recommend StackOverflow. If I missed something or you feel that I should not post this here please tell me why? If I was wrong to post this here I do apologise I am still new to all of this.

Comment: @HennoGrové this wasn't directed to you it was to the person who answered the question there is nothing wrong with the way you have asked the question

Comment: @AdityaKurkure ooh sorry my bad

Comment: No worries. :  )

Comment: The method should be after you declare the variables, in details.java class

Answer (score 0):

When exactly is incAmt supposed to be set to any value but 0? The only place where I can see that is in getUpdatedSalary() which doesn't seem to be ever called.

Using getUpdatedSalary() to both return a value and change the object's variables doesn't seem like the best idea to me. Maybe try this:

```
private double updatedSalary;
public void setUpdatedSalary () {

    incAmt = salary * 0.1;
    newSal = incAmt + salary;
    updatedSalary = incAmt + newSal;
}

public double setUpdatedSalary () {

    return updatedSalary;
}
```

And in printDetails:

```
public static void printDetails(int idNum, String name, String surname, double salary, double incAmt, double newSal){

    Details e = new Details (idNum, name, surname, salary, incAmt, newSal);
    e.setIdNum(idNum);
    e.setName(name);
    e.setSurname(surname);
    e.setSalary(salary);
    e.setincAmt(incAmt);
    e.setnewSal(newSal);
    e.setUpdatedSalary();

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employee ID Number: " + e.getIdNum()
         + "\nEmployee First Name: " + e.getName()
         + "\nEmployee Surname: " + e.getSurname()
         + "\nOrigonal Salary: R" + e.getSalary()
         + "\nIncreass on Salary: R" + e.getincAmt()
         + "\nTotal Salary: R" + e.getnewSal());
}
```

Comment: so incAmt is supposed to be 10% of the person salary, that's the thing i need to call it to display in my main class.